# Is it possible in Konva.js to draw with the left mouse button and drag the stage with the right mouse button?

Tags: javascript, konvajs

I'm trying to do an app in which you can draw custom rectangle shape objects and be able to drag your stage at the same time. Is it possible with Konva.js?

```
var stage = new Konva.Stage({ 
    container: 'container', 
    width: width, 
    height: height 
});

document.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => { 
    switch (e.button) { 
        case 0: 
            stage.draggable(false); 
            break; 
        case 2: 
            stage.draggable(true); 
        break; 
    } 
});
```

Comment: Have you done any research? Please share your research with us

Comment: Typically a UI would provide the use with a button to click to switch modes. And usually there is a palette of shapes to select from, which the selection switching the mode to drawing and on completion the mode is re-set to dragging.  Is that more like what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so if you wondering how to do it this is a possible solution:

```
var stage = new Konva.Stage({ 
    container: 'container', 
    width: width, 
    height: height 
});

document.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => { 
    if(e.button === 0) stage.draggable(false); 
});
document.addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => { 
    if(e.button === 0) stage.draggable(true); 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Konva.dragButtons` like so:

```
import Konva from 'konva';
    
Konva.dragButtons = [2];
```

Where the list represents the buttons that can be used for dragging (0=left,1=middle,2=right)

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your goals you can use this:

```js
const stage = new Konva.Stage({
  container: 'container',
  width: window.innerWidth,
  height: window.innerHeight,
  draggable: true
});

const layer = new Konva.Layer();
stage.add(layer);

const circle = new Konva.Circle({
  x: stage.width() / 2,
  y: stage.height() / 2,
  radius: 50,
  fill: 'green'
});
layer.add(circle);

layer.draw();

stage.on('contextmenu', e => {
  e.evt.preventDefault();
})

stage.on('mousedown', (e) => {
  const isLeft = e.evt.button === 0;
  stage.draggable(!isLeft); 
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="description" content="Konva demo">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/konva@^2/konva.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this one still did not allow the right mouse button to have the draggable feature...